# Pandas resample by first day in my data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, resampling

I have a Yahoo finance daily stock price imported in a pandas dataframe. I want to use `.resample()` to convert it to the monthly stock price by taking the price of the first QUOTED daily price of each month.

```
.resample('MS', how='first')
```

returns the correct price of each month **but** it changes the index to the first day of the month while in general the first day of a month for a quoted price maybe 2nd or 3rd of the month because of holidays and weekends.

How can I use `resample()` by only resampling the existing dates and not changing them?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think what you *want* is [BMS](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases) (business month start):

```
.resample('BMS').first()
```

Note: Prior to pandas 0.18 this was done using the deprecated `how` kwarg:

```
.resample('BMS', how='first')
```

---

An alternative would be to groupby month and take the first with a plain ol' groupby (and e.g. use [nth](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html) to get the first entry in each group):

```
.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')).nth(0)
```

Note: Prior to pandas 0.21 this was done using the deprecated `TimeGrouper`:

```
.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('M')).nth(0)
```

Comment: the groupby solution was what I was looking for, but it is still sort of strange to me that resample, doesnt really sample from the existing dates (like what we did in groupby). Thanks a lot Andy

Comment: @Andy Hayden This does not appear to work in the latest version of pandas.  Any thoughts on how to achieve this now?

Comment: @derNincompoop the API is now `s.resample('BMS').first()`