# pandas-resample-to-specific-weekday-in-month (MOnday before 3rd Friday)

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a pandas series s, I would like to extract the Monday before the third Friday:

with the help of the answer in following link, I can get a resample of third friday, I am still not sure how to get the Monday just before it.

[pandas resample to specific weekday in month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52495310/pandas-resample-to-specific-weekday-in-month)

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import WeekOfMonth 

s.resample(rule=WeekOfMonth(week=2,weekday=4)).bfill().asfreq(freq='D').dropna()
```

Any help is welcome

Many thanks

Comment: The Monday before the third Friday will never be in the previous month, so why not just get the third Monday? `WeekOfMonth(week=2, weekday=0)`

Comment: or just apply s1 = s.apply( lambda x: x - timedelta(days=4)

Comment: Another consideration which may not apply to your situation: Friday of the third week is not necessarily the same as the third Friday. It depends on how you count weeks. What if the month begins on Thursday? Does that week "belong" to this month or the previous?

Answer (score 0):

For each source date, compute your "wanted" date in 3 steps:

- Shift back to the first day of the current month.
- Shift forward to Friday in third week.
- Shift back 4 days (from Friday to Monday).

For a *Series* containing dates, the code to do it is:

```
s.dt.to_period('M').dt.to_timestamp() + pd.offsets.WeekOfMonth(week=2, weekday=4)\
    - pd.Timedelta('4D')
```

To test this code I created the source *Series* as:

```
s = (pd.date_range('2020-01-01', '2020-12-31', freq='MS') + pd.Timedelta('1D')).to_series()
```

It contains the second day of each month, both as the index and value.

When you run the above code, you will get:

```
2020-01-02   2020-01-13
2020-02-02   2020-02-17
2020-03-02   2020-03-16
2020-04-02   2020-04-13
2020-05-02   2020-05-11
2020-06-02   2020-06-15
2020-07-02   2020-07-13
2020-08-02   2020-08-17
2020-09-02   2020-09-14
2020-10-02   2020-10-12
2020-11-02   2020-11-16
2020-12-02   2020-12-14
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

The left column contains the original index (source date) and the right
column - the "wanted" date.

Note that *third Monday* formula (as proposed in one of comments) is wrong.
E.g. third Monday in January is *2020-01-20*, whereas the correct date is *2020-01-13*.

## Edit

If you have a DataFrame, something like:

```
        Date  Amount
0 2020-01-02      10
1 2020-01-12      10
2 2020-01-13       2
3 2020-01-20       2
4 2020-02-16       2
5 2020-02-17      12
6 2020-03-15      12
7 2020-03-16       3
8 2020-03-31       3
```

and you want something like *resample* but each "period" should start
on a Monday before the third Friday in each month, and e.g. compute
a sum for each period, you can:

1. Define the following function:

   ```
   def dateShift(d):
       d += pd.Timedelta(4, 'D')
       d = pd.offsets.WeekOfMonth(week=2, weekday=4).rollback(d)
       return d - pd.Timedelta(4, 'D')
   ```

   i.e.:

   - Add 4 days (e.g. move *2020-01-13* (Monday) to *2020-01-17* (Friday).
   - Roll back (in the above case (on offset) this date will not be moved).
   - Subtract 4 days.
2. Run:

   ```
   df.groupby(df.Date.apply(dateShift)).sum()
   ```

The result is:

```
            Amount
Date              
2019-12-16      20
2020-01-13       6
2020-02-17      24
2020-03-16       6
```

E. g. two values of *10* for *2020-01-02* and *2020-01-12* are assigned
to period starting on *2019-12-16* (the "wanted" date for December 2019).